# Delete duplicate records without using ROW_NUMBER() function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete duplicate records without using ROW_NUMBER() function (SQL Server)

Example: Table with the following data:

```
name     salary
-----------------
Husain   20000.00
Husain   20000.00
Husain   20000.00
Munavvar 50000.00
Munavvar 50000.00
```

After deleting the duplicate records
table should contains data like this:

```
name     salary
-----------------
Husain   20000.00
Munavvar 50000.00
```

Comment: Do you have an ID at least ?

Comment: What is your issue with using `Row_Number()`?

Comment: No only two column (name,salary). interviewer asked me this question in my recent interview.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the motivation for this question seems to be academic interest rather than practical use...

The table has no primary key but the undocumented pseudo column `%%physloc%%` can provide a substitute.

```
DELETE T1
FROM YourTable T1 WITH(TABLOCKX)
WHERE CAST(T1.%%physloc%% AS BIGINT)
NOT IN (SELECT MAX(CAST(%%physloc%% AS BIGINT))
        FROM YourTable 
        GROUP BY Name, Salary)
```

In reality you should never use the above and [just use `row_number`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3822833/73226) as it is more efficient and documented.

([Data Explorer Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/493352))

Comment: Thank you Martin for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Another (academic) option, depending on what version of SQL server you're using:

```
;with CTE as (select lag(name) over (order by name) as name1
              ,lag(salary) over (order by name) as salary1
              , * 
              from #table)

delete from cte where name = name1 and salary = salary1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Common Table Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)  combined with `ROW_NUMBER()` like this (This is the best way to delete duplicates):

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT t.name,t.salary
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.name,t.salary ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as rn
   FROM YourTable t
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

`ROW_NUMBER()` will assign each group randomly ranking, only one will get the rank `1` , and every thing else will be deleted.

**EDIT:** I can suggest something else with out the use of `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT distinct t.name,t.salart
INTO TEMP_FOR_UPDATE
FROM YourTable t;

TRUNCATE TABLE YourTable ;

INSERT INTO YourTable 
SELECT * FROM TEMP_FOR_UPDATE;

DROP TEMP_FOR_UPDATE;
```

This will basically create a temp table containing distincted values from your table, truncate your table and re insert the distincted values into your table.

Comment: Which part of **without** did you not understand?

Comment: Is CTE something special?

Comment: @Raj Just because the OP says not to use `ROW_NUMBER()` does not make it a bad solution.

Comment: Huh, I missed that part, just woke up :( @Raj

Comment: Agreed. But when the OP is specific about not using that function, then providing a solution using that function is kinda backwards, isn't it?

Comment: @sagi I think you need to delete this answer.

Comment: @sagi : Thanks for quick response but I want to delete it without using ROW_NUMBER() function (interview question)

Comment: Is this the only two columns available? @Munavvar

Comment: Deleting using ROW_NUMBER() is already answered. When OP explicitly says without, you should follow the point

Comment: @Munavvar I've also added a solution without `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: @sagi, I would suggest to use `TRUNCATE` instead.

Comment: @sagi nice.. is there other solution?

Comment: @Munavvar Not that I can think of, maybe using a variable with `CTE` , but I don't know SQL-Server well enough to tell you how.

Comment: Your update isn't valid SQL Server syntax. There is no `create table ... As query` in SQL Server. The equivalent is `select ... Into`. Also SQL Server doesn't allow `ORDER BY 1` in rownumber, but does allow `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)`.

Comment: @MartinSmith Good to know, fixed.

Comment: @FuzzyTree Well, I'm not required to use `#` aren't I? As you see I drop the table afterwords. And the logic came here first, so, after syntax adjustments it still won't count as a copy of a later answer..

Comment: I talked about the logic, didn't know about that difference in SQL-server .

Answer (score 1):

1. Select data from your table using `group by name , salary` (or
   `distinct`).
2. Insert into temp table.
3. Delete data in original
4. Copy data from temp table to your original table

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you can use as below

Delete from table
where rowid not in (select max(rowid) from test group by name, salary);

Comment: The question is about SQL Server.

Comment: otherwise you follow as below Create temporary table emp_temp As
Select Distinct name, salary
From   emp_temp;

Truncate table emp;

Insert into emp
Select * 
From   emp_temp;

Comment: people are so eager to give negative flag.. i agree the answer is irrelevant but @Temruzinn already said its for oracle...I am getting rid of at least one negative